# Tracing SQL Queries with X-Ray and Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp, aws-xray, tomcat-jdbc

The current X-Ray SQL tracing interceptor uses Tomcat JDBC Pool but Spring Boot 2 uses HikariCP as default pool, is it possible to configure the jdbc tracing in HikariCP instead?

Here (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=254847) they suggest to use both Datasources:

```
DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
... // data source configuration
dataSource.setJdbcInterceptors("com.amazonaws.xray.sql.postgres.TracingInterceptor;");
hikariDataSource.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

But if I have the HikariCP library in the classpath spring will configure that as datasource.

I've tried with a DatasourceBuilder and also forcing the type using the parameter `spring.datasource.type`

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring boot , you can use still use [Tomcat over HikariCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173081/how-to-replace-default-hikari-cp-to-tomcat-pool-on-spring-boot-2-0/50174452#50174452) as connection pool:

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
>     <exclusions>
>         <exclusion>
>             <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
>             <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>     </exclusions>
> </dependency>    
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
>     <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: I know but there is a reason why they now use HikariCP as default and I don't want to be forced to use tomcat jdbc pool because of X-Ray

Comment: @demetrio812 There's related open issue in HikariCP https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/579

Comment: Thanks for referencing it, they say "probably it is good to have short write up with working example class in wiki / faq for people wish to migrate from bonecp (connection hook) or tomcat jdbc-pool (interceptors)" so it could possibly something feasible?

Comment: Also do you think there is a way to mix the 2 pool like it was suggested in the aws forum post?

Comment: @demetrio812 I don't see they suggested to mix the 2 pools, but to choose one

Answer (score 0):

We are currently investigating a solution that will work with both Tomcat JDBC and HikariCP. We are aware that there are currently no work arounds without having Tomcat JDBC as a dependency. Please stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks, can you please write here when you have an update?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the same using TracingDataSource, while still using HikariCP as the connection pool

Reference https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java/issues/88#issuecomment-570328275

Code: (Note, I am using AWS Secrets Manager JDBC Library `aws-secretsmanager-jdbc` to connect to the database using secrets stored in AWS Secrets Manager)

```
import com.amazonaws.xray.sql.TracingDataSource;

...
...
@Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        return TracingDataSource
                .decorate(DataSourceBuilder.create()
                        .driverClassName("com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerPostgreSQLDriver")
                        .url("jdbc-secretsmanager:postgresql://" + System.getenv("PGHOST") + ":"
                                + System.getenv("PGPORT") + "/" + System.getenv("PGDATABASE"))
                        .username(System.getenv("SECRET_NAME")).build());

    }
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-sql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```